# Where are Angular's webpack bundles configured?

Tags: angular, webpack

With the default new Angular CLI based project and it's webpack integration some things are weird. Where are the default bundles configured?

I removed the styles.css file now the project doesn't build.

```
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 303 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 342 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\project\src\styles.css'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular CLI provides configurations options using `.angular-cli.json`. This has a defined [schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json) that defines the options that can be configured. As the Angular CLI wraps up Webpack for you, you can't get direct access to the Webpack config itself when using the Angular CLI. You have a couple of options:

1. Change the relevant settings in `.angular-cli.json`, if they fit.
2. Use [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) on your project:

   > ng eject ejects your app and output the proper webpack configuration and scripts.

   Once ejected, you can modify the Webpack configuration accordingly.

In order to fix your specific issue with `styles.css`, you can just go with option 1 and update `.angular-cli.json` to exclude this file - It's essentially specified under `apps[0].styles`, which defaults to an array with a single element: `styles.css`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `.angular-cli.json` file there is still a reference to the `styles.css`. Remove the entry from `apps.styles` as well, and it won't throw an error anymore